# How to add Google or Bing map on AngularJS-WinJS Windows Phone App?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing a Windows Phone 8.1 app using WinJs 2.1 and AngularJS 1.4. It worked fine until I needed to add either Google or Bing maps. I tried the following example but I got the following error.

`Network request to https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=visualization did not succeed.
Your application manifest does not declare the following capabilities: internetClient privateNetworkClientServer`

http://www.creepyed.com/2012/11/how-to-use-the-google-maps-api-on-windows-8/

Does anyone gone through the same issue or used something I missed to get this done?

I have added the following lines in my manifest

```
<ApplicationContentUriRules>
        <Rule Type="include" Match="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js*" />
        <Rule Type="include" Match="https://www.google.com/" />
        <Rule Type="include" Match="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/" />
        <Rule Type="include" Match="https://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx"/>
      </ApplicationContentUriRules>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="location" />
  </Capabilities>
```

Thanks!

Comment: The link you shared explains how to resolve it.

Comment: But still got the same error.

Comment: I added an additional reference (`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>`) on the map.html and now get the following error.  `SEC7117: Network request to https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=visualization did not succeed.
Your application manifest does not declare the following capabilities: internetClient privateNetworkClientServer`

Comment: You should edit your question with some code samples of what you tried.  Its too hard for others to guess whats been attempted here.  Basically though your error indicates that there is a missing reference. The second error could be resolved here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175312/how-can-i-load-remote-content-in-a-winjs-iframe-whilst-avoiding-sec7117-errors

Comment: @JasonHughes My code is the same with the example I've shown. I tried the solutions from the thread you suggested but didn't work. I'm sorry if I can explain my situation quite well.

Comment: The maps for Windows Phone 8.1 are built into the WP8.1 SDK. Look at the Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps namespace. Other than that I'm afraid you're going to have to actually show some code etc.  You might be running into a CORS problem, or just plain missing something from your manifest.

Comment: Could I use Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps control while I'm using JavaScript as main language (plus angular)?

Comment: Its XAML, the approach you are trying is an iFrame which is a WinJS control.

Comment: Look at https://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7

Comment: @JasonHughes I can't reference the `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>`. When I add it in my default page I get the error `An app can’t load remote web content in the local context` and when I add it via iframe I took the error with the capabilities. I added rules with the corresponding URIs but nothing.

Comment: Your trying to access an external resource in a local context

Comment: @JasonHughes so, is there any solution or workaround on this?

Comment: Check those links.  Some people prefetch.  Theone I mentioned yesterday was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175312/how-can-i-load-remote-content-in-a-winjs-iframe-whilst-avoiding-sec7117-errors  Looks like your issue.